How to test js/jsx with jest in react native
I am trying to test a App.js file in react native with jest but the test is passing only when the file has ts extension. By default react native created ts/tsx files and I converted them to js/jsx as I am not much familiar to typescript.
The error is:
Invalid or unexpected token.(import)
This is my babel.config
module.exports = {
presets: ['module:metro-react- 
native-babel-preset'],
plugins: ['react-native- 
reanimated/plugin'],
};

This is my jest.configure
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
};

P.S.
I have tried doing the same thing, converting ts to js and testing it with jest in new react native project. But it didn't work. Am I missing any configurations?
